# How to make text thinner in CSS?

Tags: css

When I put in a `<h1>` tag, the text looks like it has been bolded.
How do we make text thinner in CSS?

Comment: Does it happen to be a `<b>` tag?? :P

Comment: Also while asking questions, you should post some HTML and CSS code so we can see what you mean and where's the issue you're facing.

Comment: did you try font-weight: lighter?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan maybe you should being rude.

Answer (score 3):

Adjust your `font-weight` value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

```
font-weight: normal
font-weight: bold

font-weight: lighter
font-weight: bolder

font-weight: 100
font-weight: 200
font-weight: 300
font-weight: 400
font-weight: 500
font-weight: 600
font-weight: 700
font-weight: 800
font-weight: 900

font-weight: inherit
```

Comment: There's no smaller/lower/unbolded value in font-weight!

Comment: Sorry, I meant lower in the context of 100 versus 500 or lighter vs normal.

Answer (score 0):

Use font-weight:

```
div{/*pick your selector*/
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="thin-text">Some text</p>
<style type="text/css">
.thin-text {
  font-weight: 100;
}
</style>
```

Or, in-line:

```
<p style="font-weight: 100;">Some text</p>
```

Comment: 100 and lighter, which makes it thinner?

Comment: @SleekGeek the one that's supported by the font-type (100 usually means thin, 900 means XXL extrabold)

Answer (score 0):

CSS `font-weight` will do the trick. Here are some examples:

```css
.font-weight-200 {
  font-weight: 200;
}

.font-weight-300 {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.font-weight-400 {
  font-weight: 400
}

.font-weight-500 {
  font-weight: 500
}

.font-weight-600 {
  font-weight: 600
}

.font-weight-700 {
  font-weight: 700
}

.font-weight-800 {
  font-weight: 800
}

.font-weight-900 {
  font-weight: 900
}
```

```html
<h1 class="font-weight-200">font-weight: 200</h1>
<h1 class="font-weight-300">font-weight: 300</h1>
<h1 class="font-weight-400">font-weight: 400</h1>
<h1 class="font-weight-500">font-weight: 500</h1>
<h1 class="font-weight-600">font-weight: 600</h1>
<h1 class="font-weight-700">font-weight: 700</h1>
<h1 class="font-weight-800">font-weight: 800</h1>
<h1 class="font-weight-900">font-weight: 900</h1>
```

Read the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

Alternativly, you can just scale up a `<p></p>`. Example:

```css
p {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<p class="thin-header">Some big thin text</p>
In case you didn't know, 2rem is 2 times the root font size, 3rem is 3 times the font-size, and so on.
```